# jQuery ui Autocomplete with json call, why does it work by itself but not on the main page?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

Here are the two urls: [Working](http://www.curricunet.com/cuyahoga/search/test_search.cfm) And [Not Working](http://www.curricunet.com/cuyahoga/search/)

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I can get the simple version working but the other one is sending the data, receiving it and then not displaying the results.

I thought it was a css issue, but I've tried various methods to correct it and I haven't had any luck.

No javascript errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this helps, but a quick look reveals that on the test page you include this stylesheet:

```
http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css
```

But I cannot find a link to it on the 'not working' page.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice that.

Comment: also, you might want to clean up the input field you are binding the autocomplete to on the 'not working' page. it has an id of 'tags' but a name of 'course_title', and in jQuery you are binding to it via one of it's many classes. I would sync the id and name attributes and bind with the selector '#inputid'.